# System.UriFormatException error while creating web-request

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to get url as an input from the user and get all the data from the input website (to search for some content)

The code:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private string StringFromTheInput;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StringFromTheInput = urToSubmit.Value;
        var request_ = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(StringFromTheInput);
        WebResponse response = request_.GetResponse();
        Stream data = response.GetResponseStream();
        string html = String.Empty;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(data))
        {
           html = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
   }
}
```

and the input `<input type="text" name="url" id="urToSubmit" runat="server" />`

But getting the above error while establish `var request_ = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(StringFromTheInput);`
How Can I change it for what I need? 
Thanks!

Comment: Well what does the exception say?

Comment: @MaviDomates `An exception of type 'System.UriFormatException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code` Thanks

Comment: Not seeing the value of StringFromTheInput doesn't really help. This is a parsing error. Are you sure that value is a valid URL?

Comment: @MaviDomates any suggestion to do it simply?

Comment: Did you debug and validated that the input was correct?

Comment: Oh wait? This is on page load? You aren't getting the user to post?

Comment: Did you confirm that StringFromTheInput is not null?

Comment: @MaviDomates writing this don't let me enter data as input at all

Comment: @MaviDomates its weird, I'm trying again